# Загрузка xml в таблицу Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. Я использую Oracle 11g xe. Мне нужно скриптом загрузить xml файл в таблицу. Создал xml. Создал таблицу с двумя полями: test3_id - первичный ключ, и name с типом XMLTYPE. На сколько я понял в такого типа поле должна храниться xml-ка. Нашёл пример скрипта.

```
LOAD xml 
INFILE 'D:\file.xml' 
append
INTO TABLE test3
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
(test3_id, name)
```

Но почему то не работает. Выдаёт вот такую вот ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так. И желательно как нужно это сделать. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: То что вы пишите, это не операция SQL. Это специальный язык, который понимает только утилита SQL*Loader. Сохраняйте этот текст в файл и запускайте `sqlldr имя-файла-конфига`

Comment: Правда что то гугл не находит варианта "load xml", обычно начало "load data" https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb25loa.htm

Comment: [Пример загрузки XML](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16659/xdb25loa.htm#i1025595)

Comment: @Mike я написал в командной строке  sqlldr E:\\file.txt в этот txt я записал свой код. И командная строка на следующей строчке выдала мне запись control =     Что я должен указать в этой строчке? Потому что она требует что бы я что то написал.

Comment: Странно. Ощущение что он спрашивает у вас где контрол-файл, но вы же его указали ... Попробуйте ему расширение не txt а ctl сделать. Ну или на это control= еще раз указать ваш файл

Comment: @Mike я нашёл пример в интернете. Вот что получилось. Пишу sqlldr userid=Andrey/111292 а когда он просит контрол пишу E:\\file.txt и вроде как работает но выдаёт ошибку: SQL*Loader-941: Error during describe of table TEST3
ORA-04043: object TEST3 does not exist Не пойму что не так. Структуру таблицы я описал в самой теме. Что у меня сейчас не так не могу понять. Может быть вы подскажите.

Comment: Ну как бы ошибка однозначна - таблицу TEST3 в схеме пользователя под которым вы подключились он найти не может. Может  вы ее создали не там, или при создании заключили ее имя в двойные кавычки и теперь она именно маленькими буквами называется. У вас `select * from test3` то работает без ошибок ?

Comment: @Mike да спасибо я вспомнил что схема другая. Вот что получилось: C:\Users\Администратор>sqlldr userid=Mydb/111292

control = E:\\file.txt

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on ┬ё ╚■э 11 14:21:13 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved. Но почему то запись в таблицу не добавляется. Что сейчас не так?)

Comment: @Mike но на диск E где лежит файлик который я запускаю sql лодером появился файл точная копия xml только с расширением bad.

Comment: А там какой нибудь log файл еще не появился. раз в bad переписал, значит ему в этих записях что то не понравилось\

Comment: @Mike Кроме bad файла больше нечего нет. Если не сложно вы не могли бы написать какой нибудь контакт для прямой связи с вами. Удобней смог бы объяснить вам что у меня тут и как. Если конечно вас не затруднит.

Comment: А вы уверены, что bad точно такой же как исходный, может ошибки там написаны. Вот например тут https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm написано что можно задать имя лог файла. и потом у вас очень странная загрузка. Вы пытаетесь что то грузить в поле ID, у вас в исходном файле действительно на каждой строке лежит ID запятая (вы указали, что разделитель запятая) и полная XML. А на следующей строке уже следующая ID и следующая XML не содержащая запятых. И в примерах там было же гораздо интереснее, там описывали поля, писали какие то XMLTYPE ...

Comment: Да bad файл точно такой же как и xml. Я пытаюсь загрузить xml файл в поле name у которого тип XMLTYPE. Вот содержимое xml если поможет: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NAME>Сергей</NAME> Как мне её загрузить в поле name? Не данные из неё а сам файл. Может быть у меня что то не так в файле который я запускаю sql лодером? Вот и его содержимое ещё раз: load data
infile 'D:\file.xml'
append
into table test3
fields terminated by ","
(test3_id, name) Может быть я в нём что то не так сделал. Если знаете что не так покажите исправленный вариант. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: @Mike нашёл ещё вот такой вот вариант. LOAD DATA
INFILE *
INTO TABLE test3
APPEND
XMLType(name)(
lobfn FILLER CHAR TERMINATED BY ',',
name LOBFILE(lobfn) TERMINATED BY EOF
)
BEGINDATA
D:\\file.xml И вроде всё пошло нормально SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production o

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its a

Commit point reached - logical record count 1 Но когда я открыл вкладку data в таблице там вместо записи вот что отображается failed to parse SQL query:
ORA-00904: "NAME": invalid identifier То есть вроде запись добавилась, но не отображается. В чём тут ошибка?